# Does mssql_fetch_array executes a connection to the database server?

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I am developing a script that connects to a SQL Server database to fetch data and store it in a MySQL one.

One of the problems I am having is that the SQL Server is not prepared to handle heavy traffic.

At this point, I am executing a query that returns 4385 results (mssql_num_rows), and I want to loop over them. My question is if every mssql_fetch_array call connects to the database, or if the result of mssql_query is stored in memory.

I am not in the position of testing it to see if the server crashes, so that's why I have to ask before doing anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once you fetch all of the records are available.

Answer (score 1):

**mssql_fetch_array** does not connect to the database each time. It will just loop through the record fetched by mssql_query().

Refer to below given link for further understanding of mssql_fetch_array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php[mssql_fetch_array][1]

Answer (score 0):

All data retrieved from database are stored in a variable, so your loop won't connect to database!